# Flex Divs won't align even though they have the same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a problem where divs won't stay on the top of their parent-div if the image they contain doesn't have the same height as the others ones.

In my navbar I have icons of different sizes, I put them in divs on which I use `display: flex` to verticlly align the icons inside the divs. The divs all have the same height, but if the image of each div isn't identical, a small margin appear above them, as seen in this snippet :

```css
#navbar-right {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 300px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
 font-size: 0px;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #3F3F3F;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}

#navbar-right .navbar-menu {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
 height: 35px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-right">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="24"/>
    </div>
  </a>
   
  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="20"/>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="30"/>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I don't understand why this happens nor how to fix it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `display: flex` to the container:

```css
#navbar-right {
        display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 300px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
 font-size: 0px;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #3F3F3F;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}

#navbar-right .navbar-menu {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
 height: 35px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-right">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="24"/>
    </div>
  </a>
   
  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="20"/>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="30"/>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you add a `vertical-align: middle;` to the `.navbar-menu` class, it does the job.

```css
#navbar-right {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 300px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
 font-size: 0px;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #3F3F3F;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}

#navbar-right .navbar-menu {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 35px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-right">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="24"/>
    </div>
  </a>
   
  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="20"/>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="30"/>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:inline-flex` from `.navbar-menu` and add it to main container:

```
#navbar-right{ 
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

```css
#navbar-right {
  position: absolute;
  display:inline-flex;
  top: 10px;
  right: 300px;
  padding: 10px; 
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.navbar-menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-right">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="24"/>
    </div>
  </a>
   
  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="20"/>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="menu-language" class="navbar-menu">
      <img src="/core/img/language.png" width="36" height="30"/>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```